# Luis python SDK Utterance addition

Tags: python, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

we are trying to create a Chatbot using Luis framework and Python SDK using the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/sdk-python-quickstart-authoring-app#create-entities-for-the-app) as a reference. We have been able to add Intent, entity and pre-built entities using the same. These changes show up on the portal verifying the addition.

But the code for Utterance addition is not showing on the portal or being listed on the terminal.

```
def create_utterance(intent, utterance, *labels):
    """
    Add an example LUIS utterance from utterance text and a list of
    labels.  Each label is a 2-tuple containing a label name and the
    text within the utterance that represents that label.
    Utterances apply to a specific intent, which must be specified.
    """
    text = utterance.lower()

    def label(name, value):
        value = value.lower()
        start = text.index(value)
        return dict(entity_name=name, start_char_index=start,
                    end_char_index=start + len(value), role=None)

    return dict(text=text, intent_name=intent,
                entity_labels=[label(n, v) for (n, v) in labels])
utterances = [create_utterance("FindFlights", "find flights in economy to Madrid",
                               ("Flight", "economy to Madrid"),
                               ("Location", "Madrid"),
                               ("Class", "economy")),
              create_utterance("FindFlights", "find flights to London in first class",
                               ("Flight", "London in first class"),
                               ("Location", "London"),
                               ("Class", "first")),
              create_utterance("FindFlights", "find flights from seattle to London in first class",
                               ("Flight", "flights from seattle to London in first class"),
                               ("Location", "London"),
                               ("Location", "Seattle"),
                               ("Class", "first"))]

client.examples.batch(appId, appVersion, utterances, raw=True)
client.examples.list(appId, appVersion)
```

This code does not return any error but does not list the Utterances either.

Comment: indentation seems off from "utterances = ...", is it just in this stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: the indentation is happening through IDE (PyCharm) and is working good. There may be some minor mismatch while copying it on the snapshot.